# What is the direction of the weak force between electrons and protons?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, weak-interaction

Is the weak force between electrons and protons repulsive or attractive? Does it affect somehow the electron shells of atoms?

Comment: [Weak force: attractive or repulsive?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/77196/weak-force-attractive-or-repulsive?rq=1)

Comment: @AndreiGeanta Ye I have already read that, but it does not contain info (for laymans) about what weak charges the electron and proton have for example in a hydrogen atom and how this affects electron shells (if it does).

Comment: Here is what you need to know to use the answer quoted by @AndreiGeanta. The constituant  quarks, up and down, of the proton have weak isospin as per their name, and “hypercharge”. As for the electron, it counts as “down” for weak isospin and “anti-hypercharge”, again using the wording of that answer.

Comment: … for left-handed particles. For the right-handed ones, up has hypercharge, down and electron have anti-hypercharge.

Comment: @frapadingue Thanks! What does left and right handed mean?

Comment: @inf3rno, The [chirality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chirality_(physics)) of the particle