# What are the equations for the weak and strong forces?

Tags: forces, quantum-chromodynamics, interactions, strong-force, weak-interaction

What are the equations for the strong and weak force, like how for the Electrostatics the equation is $F_c= k*Q*q/(r*r)$. I understand to an extend what the strong and weak forces are. However, I would like to know what the equations for calculating the forces. Also can you explain how the equations works and define the variables.

I understand that they may not be as simple and as pretty and the electrostatic one.

Comment: Half of this question duplicates http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/8452/

Comment: Also relevant: http://xkcd.com/1489/

Comment: The weak interaction acts over such short distances and so, well, weakly compared to the strong and electromagnetic interactions that there is nothing to be gained by expressing it in a "as a function of distance" form. The only way anyone bother to write it down in as a Lagrangian or Hamiltonian contribution. I generally campaign for speaking of "four fundamental *interactions*" rather than "four fundamental forces".

Comment: Hmmm ... FrankH takes a crack at it in [this answer](http://physics.stackexchange.com/a/39255/520) to another related question. Don't know if that is really correct or not.

Comment: The question is essentially a duplicate of https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/39229/2451

Answer (score 2):

There is and there isn't an equation. What I mean is that there is no universal equation for all cases. For example, the equation for strong force $V(r) = - \frac{4}{3} \frac{\alpha_s(r) \hbar c}{r} + kr$ only applies to quarkonium. This is different for the gravity equation which applies in all cases.

Comment: Can you explain what these variables mean please?

Comment: If that is the equation for the strong force for quarkonium, is there one for the weak force as well?

Comment: V(r) is the potential of the strong force, k is field energy per unit length, c is the speed of light, and h-bar is Planck's constant over 2pi

Comment: I dont know of an equation for weak force in quarkonium

Comment: The weak force is called weak because its strength is very much smaller than the electromagnetic. In addition the 1/r potential appears in electromagnetism and gravity because the exchanged boson is massless ( photon, graviton) . The weak interaction is mediated with the W and Z which lead to immediate decays for unstable particles and no long range effects as with electromagnetism and gravity. Only at unification energies and higher one could talk of a single form for the unified electroweak force. ( I assume 1/r potential but may be wrong)