# Is there any formula for strong and weak nuclear force?

Tags: weak-interaction, strong-force

As we know, there is an equation for gravitational force

$$F = \frac{Gm_1m_2}{R^2}$$

While for electromagnetism, it is
$$F = q(E + v × B)$$
So is there any true formula to find the weak and strong force?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What are the equations for the weak and strong forces?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/169180/)

Comment: Also possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/39229, https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/8452

Answer (score 0):

Yes. In modern physics, one formulates the forces in terms of energy rather than force, as a scalar theory seems to have many advantages over a vector theory.

In 1935, quantum physicist [Hideki Yukawa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hideki_Yukawa) showed that the nuclear potential is of the form,

$$V_{\text{Yukawa}} \left( r \right) = -\frac{g^2}{r} e^ {- \mu r} $$

Where $r$ is radial distance from the interacting particle, $g$ is a scaling constant and $\mu = \alpha m$ is the particle's Yukawa mass ($\alpha$ is another scaling constant).

Coming to the weak nuclear interaction - it is, as the word suggests, better described as an 'interaction' than as a 'force'. There are various kinds of weak nuclear interactions, and finding a general structure in them requires rigorous knowledge of the [electroweak theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electroweak_interaction) (which unifies the weak nuclear interaction and quantum electrodynamics).

Comment: thanks a lot!! got it !!