# What is the equation for the non-constant coupling $\alpha_s$ for the strong force?

Tags: interactions, strong-force

I wanted to ask the question [Is there an equation for the strong nuclear force?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/8452/) but someone already has. The top answer gives

$$V(r) = - \dfrac{4}{3} \dfrac{\alpha_s(r) \hbar c}{r} + kr$$

> It is important to note that the coupling $\alpha_s$ also depends on the distance between the quarks.

What is $\alpha_s$?

Comment: $\alpha_s$ is the strong coupling constant of the strong interaction. See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupling_constant#QCD_and_asymptotic_freedom)

Comment: If it's constant then $V(r)$ is inversely proportional to $r$, but electrostatic repulsion is inversely proportional to $r^2$, so we would expect protons to fly apart at short range.

Comment: It's a running constant that depends on the energetic scale, thus from the distance.