# $\alpha_s$ strength in quarkonium potential energy formula

Tags: particle-physics, standard-model, quantum-chromodynamics, quarks

The top answer to [Is there an equation for the strong nuclear force?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/8452/is-there-an-equation-for-the-strong-nuclear-force) explains that there is a coulomb's law-like formula:

$V(r)=−\frac{4}{3}\frac{α_s(r)ℏc}{r}+kr$

that describes how quarks and antiquarks interact with each other.
The author points out that the $\alpha_s$ factor is dependent on the distance between quarks, so what is that dependency? What is $\alpha_s$ as a function of r?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The phenomenological potential you wrote is closest to the [Richardson 1979 potential](https://doi.org/10.1016/0370-2693(79)90753-6) loosely inspired by  one gluon exchange, where $\alpha_s$ decreases logarithmically with distance for ***small*** *r*,
$$
\alpha_s \propto \frac{1}{\ln (1/r^2\Lambda^2)}
$$
Λ being the QCD scale of ~200MeV or so.

Such potentials, including confinement linear terms and more functions with more adjustable parameters can be found in reviews, eqn (15a), such as [A.  Bykov,  Dremin,  & Leonidov (1984) *Usp Fiz Nauk* **143** 321](https://doi.org/10.1070/PU1984v027n05ABEH004291) ...